# Robot Framework how to get CSS or xpath

Tags: css, xpath, robotframework

I am using Browser plugin in Robot framework. I can't get the xpath or css path for MPP Status. It should give PASS(or FAIL). I have tried a few options but no luck:

`Get Text    //*[contains(text(), 'MPP Status')]//following-sibling::span`

`Get Text    //*[contains(text(), 'MPP Status')]//following-sibling::span  equal  'PASS'`

```
<table _ngcontent-c="" class="table table-vertical">
...    <tbody _ngcontent-c=""><tr _ngcontent-c="" class="ng-star-inserted">
...    <th _ngcontent-c="">MPP Status</th><td _ngcontent-c="">
...    <!---->
...    <!---->
...    <span _ngcontent-c="" class="label label-success ng-star-inserted"> PASS </span>
...    <!---->
```

Comment: I noticed that PASS in your html sample starts and ends with spaces. Have you tried with ' PASS '?

Comment: Why `td` node has no closing tag? Share correct HTML. If `span` is a child of `td` then it cannot be a sibling of `th`...

Answer (score 0):

Working one should be

```
//th[text()="MPP Status"]/following-sibling::td/span
```

Answer (score 0):

What do the `...` and `<!---->` mean? Does that mean you removed markup to try to make it look simpler? If so you're probably not showing the true hierarchy of the data.

In html tables, `th` and `td` are usually in `tr`. Assuming that's how your data is actually structured, try something like this...

```xml
//tr[td[normalize-space()='MPP Status']]/following-sibling::tr//span[1]
```

or

```xml
//tr[td[normalize-space()='MPP Status']]/following::span[1]
```

If neither of these work, we'll need to see more of the structure to determine the correct xpath.